Looking to modify Go Daddy enhanced checkout button text
I am trying to modify the go daddy enhanced checkout button text. It currently says "Pay Now" and I would like to adjust that. I'm ignorant to this but here is the html code I copied. I am wondering if someone can translate this to a PHP function I can copy into my wordpress theme file editor?
<button class="gd-btn gd-bg-primary gd-border-primary w-full" type="button" id="gd-checkout-pay-button">Pay Now</button>

I originally typed in the below which works when go daddy enhanced checkout is disabled. However, I like to keep the go daddy enhanced checkout as it is a clean look. I even tried to find the code snippet in the go daddy enhanced checkout plugin files...
function my_custom_checkout_button_text() {
    return 'My Custom Text';
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_button_text', 'my_custom_checkout_button_text' );


Checking on the support page for the GoDaddy payments plugin (https://wordpress.org/support/topic/gdp-overrides-customized-place-order-button-text/), they recommend doing the strategy you are using but they noted that it only works when you also are using the "Say What" plugin (https://wordpress.org/plugins/say-what/) with certain settings that are no longer apparent.
You will very likely need to install the "Say What" plugin, find the text domain that GoDaddy is using, then replace the GoDaddy wording with your wording through the Say What plugin interface.
Potentially you could also hack up the GoDaddy plugin but I wouldn't recommend that at all as then you wouldn't be able to easily update it when security issues inevitably get patched.

Thanks for your reply. It’s interesting because in the thread you linked the person said his custom text worked when not using Go Daddy Payments. With my site I’m only using cash on delivery so in theory it should work. Odd
